# How can I let a user to post several images to one model?

Tags: django, image, file-upload

I have one listing model :

```
class Listing(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('offerer'))
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=255)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Price"), null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'))
    time = models.DateTimeField(_('Created time'), 
        default = datetime.now,
        editable = False
    )
```

Then I have one ListingImage, which holds the pictures of the listing:

```
from photologue.models import ImageModel

class ListingImage(ImageModel):

    pictures = models.ForeignKey(Listing, related_name="images")
```

forms.py

```
class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        exclude = ('owner',) 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Why in the upload page , there is no field to upload a picture??

Comment: Well there is no image field in your `Listing` model, so why would you expect to see it in a `ModelForm` for `Listing`? Take a look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: because I am using django-photologue so I thought that would bring that photo field.

Comment: ListingImage(Imagemodel) is using the model in django-photologue so ...

Answer (score 0):

`ListingImage` has a `ForeignKey` **to** `Listing`, so a `ModelForm` for `Listing` has nothing to do with `ListingImage`.

You shouldn't be expecting a `ModelForm` for the `Listing` model to show you anything but the `Listing` model. `ListingImage` is a reverse relationship to the `Listing` model.

If this was a `ModelAdmin`, you'd get the admin site to show you these reverse relationships by defining inlines: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin

Since it doesn't look like you're talking about the admin panel, you're looking at `InlineModelFormsets`: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view

Also, you could show us your views so that we can see the whole picture.